# Very similar edits to some questions - one rejected, many others accepted

Tags: discussion, support

I'm working on a project which makes use of [Device Instance ID](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-instance-ids)s.
In my journey at developing the project, I met many questions which talk about that, until I found out there was a [device-instance-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-instance-id) tag.

The oldes question with that tag was from 2010, so I thought that the tag really meant the Microsoft Device Instance IDs.

The site asked me to provide a tag excerpt, I did it, and it was reviewed and accepted (although I admit that I may have done better at writing both the tag and the excerpt, but that's another question).

Now, I started to edit some questions which were mainly about some Android device IDs, by removing the [device-instance-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-instance-id) tag.

As you can see from my history, nearly all of them have been reviewed & accepted.

Only 2 questions which are using the [device-instance-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-instance-id) tag in a wrong way are left: one was first accepted but reverted by the OP, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23464714) has been rejected.

I'm nervous about these two questions, because I feel that they are 'polluting' the [device-instance-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-instance-id) tag, and I feel them just like some 'unfinished work' that has been left there, sitting and waiting to be done (much in the same way about I feel when there's an open parenthesis without a matching closing one.

In the meantime, I met some other questions which were talking about the Microsoft Device Instance ID, and I edited them by adding the [device-instance-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-instance-id) tag.

They have all been reviewed & accepted.

What to do about that rejected edit?

Should I stop making edits as little as removing a (wrong) tag?
Should I perform the same edit again and hope in a positive review?

Comment: You should have written a meta question to seek consensus about what device-instance-id should be for. Sounds like you didn't and just went ahead unilaterally. What's supposed to happen to all the Android questions, don't they need a suitable Android variant of this tag?

Comment: If `device-instance-id` is supposed to be about a specific Microsoft thing, then it seems that a more appropriate for the tag is `microsoft-device-instance-id` or `windows-device-instance-id`. After all, if other questions are *already* using that term but apparently not in the Microsoft/Windows context. Without a description of the tag, people could have meant all sorts of things with it.

Comment: Also...what is `instanceid` supposed to be? Without usage guidance it's literally the same as `device-instance-id` from a week ago. As in, unclear. The terms do seem differnet - an instance ID need not be device specific, so you're replacing one (previously) unclear term with a new *broader* and still unclear term.

Comment: I actually thought that the oldest 2010 questions were supposed to use the `device-instance-id` tag in the right way, and the Android ones were wrong. I opened all of them, and (although I'm not expert in the Android development world) in one of them I found a link to a documentation which was talking about a `instanceID` member. Actually, I discovered this in one of the last questions, and you can see in the rejected edit that I changed the `device-instance-id` tag with the `instanceid` one.

Comment: When you edit questions and don't have full edit privelege, you have to fix all major problems of a post. I would have rejected a lot of your edits because you ignored typos, capitalization or "thank you".

Comment: OK, I'm learning many lessons from all of your comments. I'm now feeling guilty because I was trying to bring some order but actually made many mistakes. I admit that the site **really** pushed me in the direction of writing the `device-instance-id` tag excerpt, and description. However, please note that I don't even have the privileges to edit my own written tag description/excerpt now! What to do now? It's better to stop? What if I meet other questions which are about the MS Device Instance ID, should I add the `device-instance-id` tag to them (after I fixed all post problems)?

Comment: @gog it doesn't really pay to look for cookie cutter rules on what to do. You have to do what makes sense; what makes sense is driven by context more than it is driven by rules.

Comment: @Gimby This is why I posted this question. I was worried by the negative review, and now I think that the majority of reviewers didn't put me in the right direction by accepting my edits. I'm interested in what you think that makes sense in my case, can you elaborate more? I really need and want to learn. For what I think, I would add the device-instance-id tag to other questions that talk about MS Device Instance ID, because I think that makes sense. But I'm not sure about my thinking anymore now.

Comment: @gog create a meta post to discuss what to do. Wait to see what consensus emerges (if any),

Comment: @gog - It is also unwise to rely on the reaction of reviewers of your edits. Many reviewers are pretty indiscriminate in what they approve.

Comment: @StephenC I learned that lesson, too. My `device-instance-id` tag was rejected by the first reviewer, and then accepted by the next 2. I thought my tag wiki was OK, but thanks to that negative review I learnt what could I have done to make the tag wiki better. The same applies to that one rejected question edit. Thanks to that, I written this question and I am learning many many things.

Comment: I opened a question to seek consensus on what to do with the `device-instance-id` tag from now on [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387007/6059640). Right now there's not much insterest in it, I'm linking it here to try and give it more visibility.

Comment: It seems that not much people cares about the `device-instance-id` tag, so I improved the tag excerpt and full info forward the MS definition. The tag info can be extended in the future, should it be useful for other fields / questions.