# What to do about the [device-instance-id] tag

Tags: discussion, support, tags

As I said in [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386996), in the past week I was asked by the stackoverflow site to provide a description and excerpt for the [device-instance-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-instance-id) tag.

I created one, and that was approved by review.

I'm not very proud of that tag excerpt and description; I should have written it better. I will improve it (suggest) after I see what consensus emerges from this question.

It happened that, at that time, there were some questions about the [Microsoft Device Instance ID](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-instance-ids), and others about [Android instance ID](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID).
[I have been told that I should have sought consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386996/very-similar-edits-to-some-questions-one-rejected-many-others-accepted?noredirect=1#comment710196_386996) about that, **before** deciding that the [device-instance-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-instance-id) tag would be a Microsoft thing.

I based my decision on the fact that [the oldest question that was tagged `device-instance-id` at that time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208722/how-to-get-friendly-device-name-from-dev-broadcast-deviceinterface-and-device-in), which was about the [Microsoft Device Instance ID](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-instance-ids) (I discovered others and tagged them after that).

Moreover, other than the name of the Android Instance ID (missing `instance` word), these documentation pages don't mention the word Device:

- [InstanceID](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID)
- [What is Instance ID?](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/)
- [Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids)
- [Migrate a GCM Client App for Android to Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm)

Perhaps, reviewers should have stopped me and pointing me in the right direction in the first place, but now that it's all done, what should we / I do? (I don't have full edit privileges, but I can suggest edits).

If I'll find others questions about the Microsoft Device Instance ID, should I suggest an edit and tag them [device-instance-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-instance-id)?

What about the Android questions, from which I suggested the removal of the [device-instance-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device-instance-id) tag (and it has been accepted)?

Comment: Why don't you have the privileges?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation score yet. However, I found out that I can now improve the tag wiki, which will be reviewed, but I'll wait for consensus on this question before going further. I could then link this question in the edit comments.

Comment: I think you can edit the tag wiki also at very low rep?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out Device Instance Id is also the name of the identifier describing the path to the USB device in the USB stack (at first glance it appears to be so in hardware), and so trying to make at a microsoft-only tag now looks really silly. I see spam related to it in kevent on linux.

The android instance-id is a deprecated property that doesn't identify the hardware but the installation and not very well. We probably shouldn't have a tag for that.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but in the latest USB 2.0 spec there are 7 occurrences of the `instance` word, and none of them is used with the meaning of a device instance id. If the linux world is using device-instance-id to describe a USB path to a device, well, that's what happens in Windows too (see my answer to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56885175/6059640)), so this could really be the right tag again. It only needs some extension in the tag description, and then one can combine it with `windows`, `linux`, `usb`, or some other tag in its question